# Display Date with Current Timezone in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date, angularjs-filter

How to display date with current UTC timezone abbreviation in Angular js.
For example I want to display date as SEPTEMBER 2, 2014 3:15 PM PST or SEPTEMBER 2, 2014 3:15 PM IST, etc

Answer (score 1):

AngularJS only supports 'UTC' timezone. You could refer to this [API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for details.
Instead, you could use other JS library to do this thing. Suggest using [moment-timezone.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Since version 1.4.0-rc.0 AngularJS supports other timezones too.